# Why does air traffic control react a certain way in "The Strain" S01E01?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-strain

Be warned.  **Spoilers ahead.**

I feel like I'm missing something obvious... at the beginning of episode S01E01 of [*The Strain*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2654620/), air traffic control notices the flight has simply stopped on the runway. Bishop, the guy in charge, goes to inspect. The plane is off, quiet and dark, with its door closed. The plane feels cold. Nearly all of the windows are shut.

At that point, they conclude that they must notify each and every agency to come down.  Uhh... why?  I get notifying ONE agency... or a specialist team...  but why instigate a media circus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I haven't seen the series but from what you've mentioned I concluded the following:

- Someone put the plane on the runway
- You can't get out of a commercial plane without stairs or using the emergency chute, which weren't there.
- Therefore everyone is either no longer in the plane (*How?*), unconscious or dead
- There was no distress call, so whatever occurred happened near-instantly throughout the plane.
- The cause is probably still on the plane
- It's probably either a homicidal maniac, some kind of pathogen or maybe an alien weapon
- Better call the police, the [Centers for Disease Control (CDC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centers_for_Disease_Control), and [Fox Mulder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Mulder) as there's no way to know which until someone goes in the plane.

So it sounds to me like they did the right thing.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was probably over-thinking it.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't seen the show?! haha, great answer!